# How do I create a Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 - Team Explorer add-in?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, tfs, add-in, team-explorer

Hi I want to develop a Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 - Team Explorer add-in to build timesheets for users that are integrated with Team Foundation Server. Should I use a vsix project? Or does anyone have a good link to learn about Visual Studio add-in development ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This MSDN blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jimlamb/archive/2010/02/26/extend-team-projects-and-team-explorer-in-tfs-2010.aspx) by Jim Lamb may help you dig into the right areas?